# Automatically order the SNo in table using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have couple of rows in database table (lets call it Customer), each row is numbered by SNo which gets automatically incremented by the identity property inherent in MS SQLServer. But when i delete a particular row that particular row number is left blank but I want the table to auto correct itself.

To give you a example:

I have a sample Customer Table with following rows:

```
SNo CustomerName Age

1   Dani         28
2   Alex         29
3   Duran        21
4   Mark         24
```

And suppose I delete 3rd row the table looks like this:

```
SNo CustomerName Age

1   Dani         28
2   Alex         29
4   Mark         24
```

But I want the table to look like this:

```
SNo CustomerName Age

1   Dani         28
2   Alex         29
3   Mark         24
```

How can i achieve that using LINQ to SQL in c#? This is for presentation in gridview only, **i don't want the SNo to be changed in database table**, just want to show the right order to users.

I'm using the following lines of code:

```
(db.Components.AsEnumerable().Select((iterator)=> new{iterator.SNo + 1})
```

But i'm not getting any result, how can i achieve it, i just want the sno to be incremented regardless of the value in database table

Please help me out

Thanks in anticipation

PS: please dont flag it or downvote for some reason u might delete after getting answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not alter your SNo but adds a counter (CustomerIterator) to the objects returned by LINQ.

```
var customers = model1.Customers.AsEnumerable()
  .OrderBy(x => x.SNo)
  .Select((x, iterator) => new { x.SNo, CustomerIterator = iterator + 1, x.CustomerName, x.Age });
```

The incrementation is not done by the "iterator + 1" part but by the Select overload found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx.
I just added the + 1 because the counter starts at 0

Comment: model1 is just the name of the Linq2SQL data class model i used in my test-app

Comment: no it is giving me error it is saying "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'WebStoreWithLinqSql.Component' and 'int'

Comment: Are you sure you've implemented my suggestion correctly? It works just as expected on my end. Post your implementation and I'll have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: I have asked the question again with specific details of my project. Here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873582/ordering-the-row-number-using-linqtosql-in-asp-net-c and it is solved. Please take a look at it. Thanks for the help and immediate feedback. Appreciate it !! Have a nice day !!

Answer (score 1):

1. When rendering the data, you could
   increment a counter and render that
   as the row number.
2. If you need to expose the data for
   consumption, you could add a new
   "row number" property to your class,
   then after fetching the data from
   the database iterate over the data,
   incrementing the new property.

But this seems like a rendering issue, so I would go with 1.

Comment: how can i do the incrementing of counter through linq query ? Can i have code for that ?

Comment: @user why you want to use LINQ in this unfitting situation. LINQ is better used for querying data instead of doing incrementing and updating fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `OnRowDataBound` Event and `TemplateField`.

Do this:

1. Add `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"` inside your GridView declaration:
2. Add TemplateField inside your GridView:

   ```
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Serial number">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblSerial" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
   ```
3. Add this in code-behind:

   ```
   int i = 1;
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           Label lblSerial = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSerial");
           lblSerial.Text = i.ToString();
           i++;
       }
   }
   ```

*([source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1205112.aspx/1?Gridview%20How%20to%20create%20a%20column%20that%20will%20autogenerate%20the%20serial%20number%20of%20each%20row))*